# How do I import libraries into my JavaScript-based UWP app service?

Tags: javascript, libraries, windows-10-universal

I'm writing a UWP app in JavaScript. I have an App Service declared in `package.appxmanifest`. By pointing its `StartPage` attribute to a JavaScript source file, I can control what gets executed.

Within that `.js` file, is it possible to import third-party libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`importScripts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453409.aspx) method. For example:

```
importScripts("/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js");
```